# Forum message thread in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My goal is to create a simple forum from scratch in ASP.net MVC.
Why? Because I want to learn how to.

Also relatively new to ASP.net MVC I would like to do the following.
I have a messageRepository which communicates to my message table in my DB.

I have function here called named

```
public IQueryable<Message> FindAllMessages()
    {
        return db.Messages;
    }
```

Now I also want to create an overload function which takes a message id as a parameter and then returns a list of all messages containing this parameter. 
sort of like this.

```
public IQueryable<Message> FindAllMessages(int id)
    {
        //take the id here and make it so that it returns a list 
        //with all messages containing this id 
        return db.Messages;
    }
```

So my question : Does anyone know how to do this?

Also if you think my approach is wrong please tell me.

UPDATE:

Ok I made some changes so right now I'm using a linq statement to fill a message variable like so

```
  public IQueryable<Message> FindAllMessages(int id)
    {
        var messages = from p in db.Messages
                       where p.ThreadReplyID == id
                       select p;
        return messages;
    }
```

Which is roughly what I asked for.
So my solution I'm giving all my threadReplyIDs  the same id as my ThreadID.

Answer (score 0):

What is the id parameter? If it the primary key then each message will have a unique ID value. Also are you using Entity framework? With EF you can easily do a find via

```
yourdbcontext.Messages.Find(id)
```

Comment: No my primary key is on a field called threadid. This id corresponds to the message id which also increments but is able to have duplicates because the possibility of a forummessage with the necessary replies. All replies and the forummessage in this case would have the same messageid. thanks for the quick reply btw –

Comment: On hindsight my naming convention of messageid is bad. So I decided to rename it for now to threadReplyID.